# Apache PDFBox - Not able to read all fields from PDF

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

We are trying to read a PDF and populate values in it dynamically. Based on a incoming request we run some rules and derive what PDF to use and then populate values to it dynamically. We are using Apache PDFBox version 2.0.11 and for some reason  we are facing issues with a particular PDF Template. We are not able to read some of the fields for this particular template and generated PDF is incomplete. Wondering if something to do with original PDF itself. Here is the code snippet we are using to read fields and populate it.

```
PDDocument pdfTemplate = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm  acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
acroForm.setXFA(null);
COSArrayList<PDField> list = (COSArrayList<PDField>) acroForm.getFields();
for (PDField field : list) {
     field.setReadOnly(true);
      logger.debug("Field name "+field.getFullyQualifiedName())))
      //use logic to populate value by calling field.setValue();
}
```

When we tried to print each field name we observed that more than 30 percent of the fields are missing. Can any one help on how to fix it? PDF is of 15 pages with different questions. If the issue is with Original PDF itself then what might be reason to not able read some of the fields?

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `getFields()` and update the code. If that doesn't help, please share the PDF and mention one field that is being ignored.

Comment: Hi Tilam, Thank you for responding. I double checked java doc and tried to retrieve children and it did not help. Unfortunately i could not attach PDF any where as it might violate company's policy. Is there anything you recommend me to check

Comment: One possibility is that the PDF has only widget annotations (which are page related) and not the fields (which are document related, each field can have 1-n widgets). Open the file with PDFBox PDFDebugger. In the page, move your mouse into a field area. Does the field name appear in the status bar? Another idea: in the menu, click "View", "Show internal structure", then in the tree go to Root/AcroForm/Fields. Then look at the whole structure and try to find your field. Do you find it?

Comment: Hi Tilman, I tried what you suggested and i don't see fields under Root/AcroForm/Fields. What might be the reason to not find fields over there?Do we need to fix PDF itself?

Comment: Maybe it's XFA forms. Pdfbox can't handle these. But you wrote you get some of the fields then you should see them

Comment: Total fields supposed to be around 350 but only 130 fields are displayed. We are checking if we can recreate PDF again. Wondering PDF might be corrupted.

Comment: Please do also try the other thing I mentioned, i.e. in PDFDebugger page display move the mouse to where the field is and see the name. Do the same with a field that you know is handle correctly too. If you don't see the name then you're using an old version of PDFDebugger.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and field that have issues does not show up in status bar below and displays fine for others. I am using 2.0.11 PDFDebugger

Comment: In that case there must be something (a huge tree that can be expanded) in `Root/AcroForm/Fields`. Because that is the path that PDFDebugger goes to collect all the available fields and then the widgets to bring the status bar effect.

Comment: Our business operation reconstructed PDF again and now we are able to retrieve all the fields. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I suggest to either delete the question or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have hierarchical fields on that form. Try something like the code below instead...

```
PDDocument pdfTemplate = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();    
PDAcroForm  acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDFieldTree fieldTree = acroForm.getFieldTree();
Iterator<PDField> fieldTreeIterator = fieldTree.iterator();
while (fieldTreeIterator.hasNext()) {
    PDField field = fieldTreeIterator.next();
    if (field instanceof PDTerminalField) {
        String fullyQualifiedName = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
        logger.debug("Field name "+fullyQualifiedName);
    }
}
```

PDAcroForm.getFields() only gets the root fields, not their children. PDAcroForm.getFieldTree() gets all fields but then you need to test to see if they're terminal before setting a value. Non-terminal fields can't have a value and don't have widgets (representations on the page) associated with them. You'll know this is the problem if the fully qualified name has periods in it. The periods represent the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you joelgeraci for suggestion. Using FieldTree also did not help.

Comment: Can you post the PDF somewhere so I can look at the specifics?

Comment: joelgeric, Unfortunately i could not attach PDF any where as it might violate company's policy. Is there anything you recommend me to check?

Comment: Can you replace the underlying page with a blank one and post a PDF with just the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after reconstructing the whole PDF again.